# Grabbing name of column in sql using the same recordset information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's my table in SQL with some sample data

```
id     cName             sub
---    ----             -----
1      ABC Company        0
2      Smith's Inc.       0
3      Ing Inc.           2
```

What I'm trying to do is use a SQL statement that will give me the name of the sub of a recordset if there is a sub, if not then just give me dashes or something. I tried doing something like this but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT cName,(
    SELECT cName 
    FROM table1 tbl 
    WHERE tbl.clientID=tbl.sub) as pName 
WHERE ID=3
```

The results should look like this

> Ing Inc., Smith's Inc

Here's what the real query looks like:

```
"SELECT cName,(
        SELECT tbl.cName 
        FROM CSA.dbo.clients tbl 
        WHERE tbl.clientID=tbl.sub) as pName, 
 FROM clients cl 
 INNER JOIN CSA.dbo.Clients c 
 ON c.clientID=cl.clientID WHERE cl.clientID=3"
```

Sub doesn't actually exist in the cl (clients) table, but in another db table called clients (c).

This doesn't seem to be working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add information showing the real columns of both clients tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `SELF-JOIN` on `clientID = sub`:

```
SELECT
    cl.cName,
    ISNULL(sc.cName, '-') AS pName
FROM cleints cl
INNER JOIN CSA.dbo.Clients c
    ON c.clientId = cl.clientID
LEFT JOIN CSA.dbo.Clients sc
    ON sc.clientID = c.sub
WHERE cl.clientID = 3
```

Comment: I edited my question. I left out a bit of information that might clear things up. This sql wouldn't work with my scenario

Comment: yea... i apologize... couldn't think straight, been trying to figure this out for a while and my head hurts :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your query should look like:

```
SELECT t.cName,
    (SELECT cName FROM table1 tbl WHERE tbl.ID=t.sub) as pName
from table1 as t
WHERE t.ID=3
```

Comment: That won't work. The query is a lot more complicated. Here's what it looks like: "SELECT cName,(SELECT tbl.cName FROM CSA.dbo.clients tbl WHERE tbl.clientID=tbl.sub) as pName, FROM clients cl INNER JOIN CSA.dbo.Clients c ON c.clientID=cl.clientID WHERE cl.clientID=3". Sub doesn't actually exist in the cl (clients) table, but in another db table called clients. They share the same clientID so i was linking them that way

Comment: sub doesn't exist in the "t" table, only in the "tbl" table.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the names of a client (i.e., a given client ID) from clients tables which live in two different (but linked or otherwise cross-accessible) DBs, right? This should do it, though you need to execute it from within the context whatever DB the "cl" clients table lives in:

```
 SELECT cl.cName,
   ISNULL(c.cName,'-') as pName 
 FROM clients cl 
 LEFT JOIN CSA.dbo.Clients c 
   ON c.clientID = cl.sub
 WHERE cl.clientID = 3
```

As an aside, I recommend actually returning null rather than using dashes to represent missing data. This way you know that there's really nothing there, and that nobody entered "-" as the name.